# Set the actual x, y position of a window

Tags: x11, xlib, xcb

I'm writing a reparenting window manager, and some apps like Firefox misbehave when I move the window. For example, say I map firefox at (0, 0). Then I move it to (5, 5). When I open a menu, it will be offset by (5, 5), because it thinks the app's coordinates are (0, 0) but the actual frame window has been moved to (5, 5).

I do set the _NET_FRAME_EXTENTS property properly, but this still occurs. How do I tell the client application what it's *actual* x and y coordinates are, without configure_window'ing (and therefore actually moving it to some offset within a frame which breaks the whole thing) it?

Maybe also worth mentioning, after I move the window, if I resize it (and the frame, of course); it apparently works fine. so, i tried this strategy:

- resize it to the height I want - 1 and the width I want
- resize it to the height I want
  I have no idea why this works, doing -1 on the width also works. in fact I can do any operation, just the result has to be that the window is resized, no matter how tiny, and firefox recieves the new coordinates. am I stuck with this hack or can I do better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess. My guess is that you are not following ICCCM § 4.2.3:

> If the window manager moves a top-level window without changing its size, the client will receive a synthetic ConfigureNotify event following the move that describes the new location in terms of the root coordinate space.

https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html#s-4.2.3

When you just move your frame windows, the client does not get a notification. Thus, these synthetic ConfigureNotify values are required.

Comment: This does it, thanks yet again!